# Configuring the REST server with a persistent data store

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am having problems trying to deploy the rest server with persistence storage (mongo db) I ge this message  when deploying the rest server:

docker logs -f rest
[2018-03-12 00:01:13] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
[2018-03-12 00:01:14] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
[2018-03-12 00:01:14] PM2 log: App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
    at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:699:34)
    at 
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
[2018-03-12 00:07:03] PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server] with id [0] and pid [14], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

I am using composer v.18

is there any work around to fix this error. when I run the composer-rest- server alone it work. but if I try to add the mongodb it does not work

Comment: Does the REST server work in Multi-User Mode without the Persistence to Mongo?  Does it work in a container without Mongo?  Can you share your Dockerfile, Your docker run command, and your environment variables.

Comment: thanks for your comments, this helped me. I  had to fix some issues with the local host config. now,  I have a rest server witth persistent database and authorization set with githup, I got authorized on the rest server and imported the network card. however, but when I try to process are request from the angular app generated, I get Error: 401 - Unauthorized. can you tell my how I can get angular app authorized?